# I'd like to copy every value in a range and paste the first one to the first sheet, the second one to the second sheet, and so on

Tags: excel, vba

All values should be pasted into the same cell on different sheets.I've written some code, but because I'm new to vba, I'm having a hard time finishing it.

````
Dim wb As workbook
set wb = thisworkbook

dim startsheet as worksheet
set startsheet = wb.sheets("start")

dim r as range
set r = startsheet.Range("C2:C6")

dim sh as worksheet
dim c as range

for each c in r
 for each sh in worksheets


 next
next```
````

Comment: Should the content of C2 to C6 be copied from the start sheet to all the sheets in the workbook?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is one way to do it:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim startsheet As Worksheet
Set startsheet = wb.Sheets("start")

Dim r As Range
Set r = startsheet.Range("C2:C6")

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Worksheets
     sh.Range(r.Address).Value = r.Value
Next sh
```

No need to loop every cell, just copy the entire range at once to save some time and code.

```
For i = 1 To r.Count
    If Not i > Worksheets.Count Then Worksheets(i).Range("D3").Value = r.Item(i, 1).Value
Next i
```

This will put "the first item on the range (C2) goes to the first sheet in cell D3, the second item (C3) goes to the second sheet in cell D3, and so on."
No idea why `D3`, but there you are.

```
For i = 1 To r.Count
    If Not i + 1 > Worksheets.Count Then Worksheets(i + 1).Range("D3").Value = r.Item(i, 1).Value
Next i
```

Just + 1 the worksheet number to skip the first sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This does work, but it copies the entire list, whereas I want to copy the contents of the list one by one. For example, the first item on the range (C2) goes to the first sheet in cell D3, the second item (C3) goes to the second sheet in cell D3, and so on. For all sheets, the cell into which the value is pasted is the same.

Comment: I think you need to add some explanation to your question in regards to exactly what your result is supposed to be, because I'm not following your logic. Like an example of expected output.

Comment: I have a list of names that I must enter one by one into cell D3 on each sheet. Because the first sheet contains the list, the first name of the list goes to the second sheet, the second name to the third, and so on. It requires a loop through all of the cells in the range. C2, for example, goes to the second sheet, while C3 goes to the third sheet. I'm hoping this makes sense.

Comment: That seemed more reasonable, but you did say "the first item on the range (C2) goes to the first sheet in cell D3". And code is very literal.

Comment: The code is completely functional. Thank you very much for your assistance.